# Jquery datepicker change event trigger and input's default change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have datepicker

```
  <input type='text' class='inp'>  
<script>
   $('.inp').datepicker();

  $(".inp").on("change",function (){ 
   console.log('inp changed');
  });
</script>
```

When I first change '.inp' manually type there a value, then immediately I click on datepicker's opened calendar. I get two 'change' event listeners. First from manual change, then from datepicker change.
How can I avoid this?

Comment: Unrelated: Your closing tag is wrong, it should be `</script>`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set your input `readOnly`, it will help you to change the value of field through icon only.

```
<input type='text' class='inp' readOnly />
```

then use `onSelect` to get selected date, as following:

```
$(function() {
    $(".inp").datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            // alert(dateText);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: setting attribute `readOnly` may disable validation (if any) for this field. In my opinion, is best solution is set attr `onkeydown="false"`

Answer (score 6):

Try using the onSelect function like:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
        onSelect: function() {
        //your code here
    }});
```

This will be fired when they select a date from the calendar not when they are typing.

Answer (score 3):

You can have onSelect trigger the change event on the text field.   This way editing the date via the text box or via the date picker behave the same.

```
$('.inp').datepicker({
  onSelect: function() {
    return $(this).trigger('change');
  }
});
    
$(".inp").on("change",function (){ 
   console.log('inp changed');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the bootstrap datepicker you can do the following:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker()
    .on('changeDate', function(e){
        # `e` here contains the extra attributes
});
```

For more details view: [Bootstrap Datepicker events](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/events.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! Everybody, but I could not make field readonly one, this is requirement. So I had to reasearch myself. So I posting my final solution. I did unbinding for 150 ms, then bind again.
[I made a jquery plugin for this](https://github.com/kostia-lev/jquery_timeout_event)

```
function myfunc(that){
        $(that).one('change', function(){
                var that = this;
                setTimeout(function(){myfunc(that);}, 150);
                //some logic
            }
        )
}

myfunc(".inp");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone, this is what I used though,

```
function myfunction(x,x2){
    var date1 = new Date(x);
    var MyDateString; 
    MyDateString = date1.getFullYear()+ '/' + ('0' + (date1.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '/' + ('0' + date1.getDate()).slice(-2);
    x2.value=  MyDateString;    
 }
```

x, being the datepicker value and x2 being the datepicker object

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  $(function() {
        $("#birth_date").datepicker({
        onSelect: function() {
            console.log("You Code Here");
        }});
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using datepiker ui you can also used following formate

```
<input type='text' class='inp'>  
 <script>
$('.inp').datepicker({

onSelect: function(date) {

      $(this).change();
    },
}).on("change",function (){ 
   console.log('inp changed');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, @krunal, but it would help to add some context around why this will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css"/>
<script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    var j = jQuery.noConflict();
    j(function() {
        j("#datepickerFrom").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
            onSelect: function () {
                var date = $(this.value).selector;
                document.getElementById("dateFrom").value = date;
            },
        }).on("change",function (){
            var date = $(this.value).selector;
            document.getElementById("dateFrom").value = date;
        })
        .datepicker("setDate",document.getElementById("dateFrom").value);
});
</script>

<input id="datepickerFrom"/>
<input type="hidden" name="dateFrom" id="dateFrom"/>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

if you are using date picker of jquery there is no need of calender event fire.
you can fire the event on textbox "textchanged"

Comment: if you are using textbox in calender then you cau use this above approach.