# Change event with jQuery datepicker and Angular 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, angular

I have some problems to catch the change event when I  use the jQuery datepicker plugin and I'm trying to use the (change) method to catch the change but seems that when I'm using this plugin, angular can't catch it.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'foo-element',
    template: '<input type="text" (change)="checkDates($event)" id="foo_date_picker" class="datepicker">'
})

export class FooComponentClass implements AfterViewInit {

    ngAfterViewInit():any{
        $('#end_day').datepicker();
    }

    private function checkDates(e){
        console.log("Please, catch the change event ): ");
    }
}
```

I have removed the datepicker initialization and works fine, but when I use it again... don't works.

Someone can help me!

Thanks so much.

Comment: the jquery datepicker will override the change event of element with it's own logic, please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506111/jquery-datepicker-change-event-trigger-and-inputs-default-change-event

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but the problem is when I try to compile the file, I show an error like this one: "Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'onSelect' does not exist in type 'DatepickerOptions'" for this reason I can't compile the source code.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement the following directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[datepicker]'
})
export class DatepickerDirective {
  @Output()
  change:EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    $(this.elementRef.nativeElement).datepicker({
      onSelect: (dateText) => {
        this.change.emit(dateText);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

This way you will be able to catch a `change` event like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: '<input type="text"  id="end_day" (change)="checkDates($event)" class="datepicker" datepicker>',
  directives: [ DatepickerDirective ]
})
export class App implements AfterViewInit {
  checkDates(e){
    console.log("Please, catch the change event ): "+e);
  }
}
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/TVk11FsItoTuNDZLJx5X?p=preview

Comment: Your answer doesn't work but you have you've taught me another way to use the angular 2 components!
Thank's!