# jQuery in Angular2 not working

Tags: jquery, angular

I am trying to get jQuery to work in my angular2 application. 
I am unable to post all of my code here but I will try to elaborate as much as I can. Any pointers would be appreciated.

my root app.ts file looks something similar to this

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
import {Component,provide,DynamicComponentLoader,Injector,OnInit,AfterViewInit,ViewEncapsulation} from 'angular2/core';

declare var jQuery:JQueryStatic;

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: './app/app.html',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})

export class app implements OnInit,AfterViewInit{
 constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef)
ngOnInit() {
        this.dcl.loadIntoLocation(HeaderComponent, this.elementRef, 'header');
        this.dcl.loadIntoLocation(FooterComponent, this.elementRef, 'footer');
    }
    ngAfterViewInit() {
           (<any>jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('.datepicker').datepicker());
    }
}
```

I am using bootstrap datepicker and am expecting the widget to fire when I click on an input with the `datepicker` class. But I can't get this to work.

I can get `(<any>jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).hide());` to work but not datepicker event.

Comment: I think you must be getting some errors in console. do you? if so what is that?

Comment: No errors in console.

Comment: isn't there any additional `datepicker.js or something` needed? I guess so.

Comment: There is. It is in included in the index.html as a script tag.

Comment: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-datepicker look at here. have you added it? I guess after adding appropriate compatible version, it will start working.

Comment: I have done it locally `<script src="/assets/components/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult to help you like this without the content of the `app.html` file ;-)

I implemented a directive to wrap jquery datepicker:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[datepicker]'
})
export class DatepickerDirective {
  @Output()
  change:EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    $(this.elementRef.nativeElement).datepicker({
      onSelect: (dateText) => {
        this.change.emit(dateText);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I apply it this way:

```
<input type="date" datepicker/>
```

See this question for more details:

- [Change event with jQuery datepicker and Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36841091/change-event-with-jquery-datepicker-and-angular-2/36841904#36841904)

and this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/TVk11FsItoTuNDZLJx5X?p=preview.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. But I wish there was a way to just assign an event to every datepicker selector as such `$('.datepicker').datepicker();` at one place and be done with it rather than assigning an attribute for every occurence and defining the directive. Maybe, I'm not thinking Angular?